# Extra whitespace

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, user-interface

I see extra whitespace in the page headers of SO/SU/SF/MSO with Chrome 4.0, Opera 10, and Firefox 3.0.  Is it intentional?  Could it be removed?

[extra whitespace http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/1372/screenshotkp.jpg](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/1372/screenshotkp.jpg)

Comment: How is that "Extra"? Isn't that just whitespace? You're just showing off your new `tools` link, aren't you?

Comment: oh come on... It doesnt seem to be bug...

Comment: Maybe bug is too strong (though seems the best out of the required tags), but it always appeared extra *and unintentional* to me, and I chalked it up to being either a Chrome bug or an unexpected interpretation of the SO styles.  It was only when I happened to use a different browser on SO that I realized it wasn't Chrome-specific.

Comment: As to showing off, nope.  I tend to use MSO in spurts, and today was because of finding out about the recent close-reason explanation changes (which was a feature I requested).  While I was here, thought I'd post a bug report on an issue that would improve SO for me (minor yes, but still improve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if your name is Rufus Xavier Sarsaparilla Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious The Third Twice Removed?

Or, if you're Jon Skeet and have 5 skadillion badges and rep?

Or, if you have access to several additional topnav menus that regular users don't?

(It's because the topnav bar can extend all the way across to the left.)

Comment: I wonder who is going to be the first to change their Meta user name to Rufus Xavier Sarsaparilla Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious The Third Twice Removed...

Comment: @balpha: somebody who hasn't changed his name for 30 days, of course.

Comment: @voyager: Yes, you're out.

Comment: I'm so tempted.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if this whitespace was taken away, it would look really heavy, cluttered. This whitespace is important to keep it "light", I think.

So I guess it's only a matter of personal opinion, here.

Comment: Given the reaction, I guess so.  I had honestly never even considered it was intentional until posting---it looked ugly to me since the beginning.  (Obviously I've lived with it so far, but since my normal browser is the beta/dev version, some things you just live with.)